# Как вернуть значение функции

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

У меня есть код на node.js с модулем request похожий на этот:

```
var request = require('request');

function name(/*параметры*/) {
    var response = '';
    var options = {
    /*
    */
    }
    function callback(err, httpResponse, body) = {
        response = //Действия с body
    }
    request(options, callback);

}

console.log(name(/*параметры*/));
```

Мне нужно что-бы функция name при вызове возвращала значение response. Мне не нужен console.log, это скорее было для условности.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дело в том что сделать это так как вы хотите чтоб прям функция вернула можно лишь одним способом с помощью async/await.

```
var request = require('request');
( async() => {
function name(/*параметры*/) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       var response = '';
       var options = {
       /*
       */
       }
       function callback(err, httpResponse, body) = {
           response = //Действия с body
           //// после действий с responce отравляем его в ответ
           resolve(responce);
       }
       request(options, callback);

       } 
    })

    console.log( await name(/*параметры*/));
})();
```

Обернул код  в IIFE функцию, так как await можно использовать только внутри async

Answer (score 1):

```js
const request = (options, callback) => setTimeout(() => callback(null,{},'response'),1111);

// Вариант 1: Callback
function name( callback, ...params) {
    var options = params;
    request(options, (err, httpResponse, body) => {
        let result = body.toUpperCase();
        callback(null, result);
    });
}
name((err,result) => {
    console.log(result);
});


// Вариант 2: Promise (то же самое, только в сахаре)
function name_promised(/*параметры*/) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var response = '';
        var options = {/**/}
        request(options, (err, httpResponse, body) => {
      let result = body+' promised';
            resolve(result);
        });
    });
}
name_promised(/*параметры*/).then(result => {
    console.log(result);
});

// Вариант 3: async/await (еще больше сахара)
(async () => {
    let result = await name_promised();
    console.log(result);
})();
```

Последний вариант удобно использовать с [промифицированным модулем request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise), примерно так -

```
const request = require('request-promise');
(async () {  
    let body = await request(options);
    console.log(body);
})();
```